# Fix the words and remove the unwanted spaces between splitted word using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, space

I have extracted the list of sentences from a document. I am pre-processing this list of sentences to make it more sensible. I am faced with the following problem

I have sentences such as `Java is a prog rammng lan guage. C is a gen eral purpose la nguage.`

I would like to correct such sentences using a look up dictionary? to remove the unwanted spaces.

The final output should be `Java is a programmng language. C is a general purpose language.`

I need help with some pointers to look for such approaches. How to solve the above problem?

I want to solve the above problem using python code. Thanks.

Comment: You could try looking up each pair of adjacent words in a dictionary of valid words, but that would get false positives, e.g. "Cis". Most approaches will have that problem.

Comment: @PeterWestlake but how to solve the other words  like `la nguage`

Comment: @Akshay As Peter already said, you could combine *each adjacent pair* of words and try looking *that* up to check if it's valid.  You probably would want to do this *only* if the individual fragments aren't already valid words (so that "C" and "is" would be left alone).  Even better would be if you had English word frequency so that you could rate some constructions better than others.

Comment: Also, *how* did you end up with these sentences in the first place?  Maybe that problem could be better solved?  Also, do you expect "prog rammng" to be converted to "programmng" even though it has a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple script that works for your example. Obviously you'd want a bigger corpus of valid words. Also, you'd probably want to have an `elif` branch that looked back at the previous word if joining the next word failed to fix a non-word.

```
from string import punctuation

word_list = "big list of words including a programming language is general purpose"
valid_words = set(word_list.split())

bad = "Java is a prog ramming lan guage. C is a gen eral purpose la nguage."
words = bad.split()

out_words = []
i = 0
while i < len(words):
    word = words[i]
    if word not in valid_words and i+1 < len(words):
        next_word = words[i+1]
        joined = word + next_word
        if joined.strip(punctuation) in valid_words:
            word = joined
            i += 1
    out_words.append(word)
    i += 1

good = " ".join(out_words)
print(good)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need spellcheck if you want the words to be spelled and parsed correctly. Here is a spellchecker, used by importing the "re" namespace, with the full article [here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)...

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())

WORDS = Counter(words(open('big.txt').read()))

def P(word, N=sum(WORDS.values())): 
    "Probability of `word`."
    return WORDS[word] / N

def correction(word): 
    "Most probable spelling correction for `word`."
    return max(candidates(word), key=P)

def candidates(word): 
    "Generate possible spelling corrections for `word`."
    return (known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known(edits2(word)) or [word])

def known(words): 
    "The subset of `words` that appear in the dictionary of WORDS."
    return set(w for w in words if w in WORDS)

def edits1(word):
    "All edits that are one edit away from `word`."
    letters    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
    deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R]
    transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]
    replaces   = [L + c + R[1:]           for L, R in splits if R for c in letters]
    inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in letters]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

def edits2(word): 
    "All edits that are two edits away from `word`."
    return (e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1))`
```

Not only does it fix split words, but also deletes, transposes, and inserts the irregular words to "correct" them. You can replace the "big.txt" file with the document you are using in the Counter constructor, and hopefully everything will work from there.